# Read csv with unquoted carriage return

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I'm creating a csv file in python using the csv writer, i then try and read the file but because one of the values has a carriage return in it the csv reader doesn't parse the rows correctly, it sees the \r as a row separator, example code:

```
import csv

value = 'a string with \r in it'

with open('test_file', 'wt', newline='', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator='\n', escapechar='"')
    csv_writer.writerow([value])


with open('test_file', 'rt', newline='', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(f, lineterminator='\n', escapechar='"')
    value_from_csv_file = next(csv_reader)[0].strip()

print(f'value: {repr(value)}')
print(f'value_from_csv_file: {repr(value_from_csv_file)}')
assert value_from_csv_file == value # this fails
```

Is there a way to make this work without using QUOTE_ALL? Is there a way to define in the reader to quote carriage returns with QUOTE_ALL?
i don't understand why python creates a file it doesn't know how to read

The file created looks like this:

```
bash-4.2# hexdump -c test_file
0000000 357 273 277   a       s   t   r   i   n   g       w   i   t   h
0000010      \r       i   n       i   t  \n
0000019
```

there is 1 line created with 1 value that has in it a carriage return, later the reader interprets this as 2 lines even though the carriage return should be treated as part of the value

NOTE: i'm using python3.10

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, if you take a look at your CSV file, you should indeed have 2 rows. So there are indeed two different rows in your CSV file. From what I understand, the issue doesn't come from the part where you read the file : you read it correctly. But when you make it, you write 2 different rows. Am I correct ?

Comment: @LoïcRibere The OP's code is a [mre] and you can easily try it yourself. The file the code creates has a single line with a literal `\r` in the middle of it, and no quotes around it.

Comment: I would report this as a bug to the Python maintainers, though this is a very marginal use case.

Comment: When I copy paste OP's code in Pycharm and run it, the file I got has 2 lines, whether in Open it in Notepad++ or in Pycharm directly.

Comment: @LoïcRibere i've added the content of the test file, the UIs you are looking at are treating \r as a new line

Comment: Agree with @Binyamin, Pycharm and notepad might consider both \r and \n as new line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## `csv.reader` ignore lineterminator

https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.lineterminator

> Note: The **reader** is hard-coded to recognise either '\r' or '\n' as end-of-line, and **ignores lineterminator**. This behavior may change in the future.